# deleting pointers with multiple references stored

Tags: c++, pointers

I create objects via new at one place in my program (let's call them actors). Those objects get passed to another object (let's call it a projectile) via their pointer. At any point that actor object can be deleted outside of projectile. delete and setting to NULL happens with this. However a pointer of it is still in projectile. I do check if != NULL but it passes those checks. The values inside the class are all bogus but the pointer itself isn't NULL.

Do I need to do a pointer to a pointer or something? I just thought if I passed a pointer around and at some point deleted and set that pointer to NULL all the other places I passed it would show NULL as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you thought about double indirection ?

1. Use a map of `Actors`: `std::map<unsigned, Actor>`
2. Only ever store the `Actor` ID in the projectiles

Now, supposing a monotonically increasing ID (you have about 4 billions of them available, should keep you going for a while), an ID being absent from the map means the `Actor` disappeared (was deleted).

Comment: pointer to a pointer is how I'll pass these objects and then check that against NULL. did a small test and it works. thanks for the suggestion though.

Answer (score 5):

You should probably look into smart pointers, like [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr).